# Invalid LOC Header (Bad Signature) in war

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jena, semantic-web

I am getting a failure with the message

```
Invalid LOC Header(Bad Signature)
```

all over the place.

I have found out allready that its because of a bad jar. This is the jar:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

This is the one that gives me the error when included. Anyone any idea how to solve this? I really need this jar and it works inside the editor and when unittesting but deployed it doesnt work at all.

Pls help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your `.m2/repository` folder and build again. It could be found under `C:/Users/yourUser`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the whole maven local repository you could only delete the bad/corrupted jar and build your project again. 
Jar will be in the folder - `{maven_repo}\org\apache\jena\3.6.0\`

Deleting whole repository is a time consuming process.